# Display razor from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, razor, syntax

I am trying to display content such as

```
<p>Text and link - @Html.ActionLink("Link", "Action")</p>
```

from a database, but if I use `@Html.Raw` then it doesn't render the link.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a Razor parser in order to achieve that. Checkout [`RazorEngine`](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) which could be used render the Razor markup to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

print it on the backend using this:

```
string template = "Hello @Model.Name! Welcome to Razor!";
string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { Name = "World" });
```

pass the results to front end using a model which contains the result in a string property.

you will need to install the following:

> Install-Package RazorEngine