# Render razor from database or other sources

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I would like to render the razor code from the database to to a razor view. Would thatbe possible?

**CONTROLLER/ACTION:**

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
    ViewBag.RazorCode = "@Html.TextBox(\"txtTestRazor\")";
    return View();
}
```

**VIEW:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

<p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>

<h3>@ViewBag.RazorCode</h3>
```

**HTML/OUTPUT:**

> About.
>
> Your application description page.
>
> Use this area to provide additional information.
>   **@Html.TextBox("txtTestRazor")**

Comment: What features of razor do you need to support?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218454/asp-net-mvc-load-razor-view-from-database

Comment: Or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174952/display-razor-from-database

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine)

Basics are very easy, just give it a string (and a model)

```
string template = "Hello @Model.Name! Welcome to Razor!";
string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { Name = "World" });
```

It doesn't support html helpers, routing etc. out of the box (as far as I remember).